# incompatible types error

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Result
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int numa;
    int numb;
    int sum;
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter 1st Number: ");
    numa=Integer.parseInt(num1);
    String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter 2nd Number: ");
    numb=Integer.parseInt(num2);
    {
        sum=num1+num2;
    }

    if (sum>=10)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations"+sum);
        else if(sum<10)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"the sum of the number less than 10");
            else if(sum>100)
                System.exit(7);
}
}
```

Comment: OMG dude, where is the error?  What is the specific question?

Comment: i trying to make a coding that allow user to give 2 number ..and the program will determine if the number more than 10 or less than 10..if the sum of both number more or equal 10..the output"Congratulations" will appear and if less than 10 the output should be"the sum of the number less than 10" but after sum of the number reach 100 the program will close..but i have error"incompatible types" error at sum=num1+num2; pls help me..and tell any error than i cant see here

Comment: You should add this explanation inside the question body @Ezwan Abid

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
sum=num1+num2;
```

is trying to add two strings together and make an `int`.

Instead, you want:

```
sum = numa + numb;
```

In other words, take the values you've just *parsed* from the strings, and add those together.

Additionally, I'd suggest:

- Where possible, declare variables at the point where you first use them (typically assignment)
- Don't add braces just for the sake of it (e.g. for this `sum` line) but...
- ... *do* add braces to all `if` blocks for clarity
- Indent all code appropriately (there should never be two braces lining up as per the end of your method)
- Unless you *really* need to use Swing, don't bother - this app would be simpler if it took input from the console and just wrote the answer to the console, instead of showing a message box.

Comment: yes thx i made it ..but i have another problem here..how to make my program close after user give sum of number more than 100 ?
big thanks for who helping me :)

Comment: `if (sum > 100) System.exit(0);` But your `if-else` statements are wrong, try to check them your own.

Comment: @EzwanAbid: If you have another problem, I suggest you ask another question. It sounds like you probably want a loop...

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: That's a pretty nasty way of doing it, IMO. Calls to `System.exit` should be pretty rare IMO. Just looping until the condition is met and then letting `main` finish should be enough.

Comment: loop...means i need to make new coding ? ok i will post it soon enough..let see how my hand doing loop now . Big Thanks for u @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet: I know, but there is definitely no context about this question. It was a code copy-past. The looping you talk about is something you assumed. But, as I said, you are correct (of course...).

Comment: @EzwanAbid: Yes, you'll need to write more code. After all, you'll need *something* to ask the user for fresh values, won't you?

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = numa + numb
```

You were trying to add the two strings.

Edit: skeeted again!